# uTorrent download finished, but files are showing 0 bytes

Tags: windows, windows-xp, bittorrent, utorrent

Got a machine running Windows XP (Please don't ask why) and used uTorrent to make a magnet download. The download finished. When I checked the files, they were all showing the proper size when I passed the mouse over them, but if I open their properties, they're showing 0 bytes of size, both read only and invisible check boxes are marked, I can't copy, move, delete, rename them. I already deleted the torrent from the list, so it means now the files are not being used by utorrent anymore, but that's it, they're there and I can't touch them.
Funny thing is that before I could open them from utorrent, as they're video files. They would open with Windows Media Player Classic.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilcUh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
You have to go to the torrent file list, in uTorrent download, then select the files you want (The ones that have been already downloaded) and reallocate them to another directory. That's because even though you may have ignored all the other files and the download is shown as 100%, the program won't delete the PART file inside the files folder. When the PART file is deleted is when the torrent actually finished the whole download process. So when you reallocate the files you need, you're basically telling the program that that part is not a part of the download process anymore. Solved the uTorrent 0 bytes issue.